# Is an IMU required to run Turtlebot stack?

Tags: imu, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is an IMU required to run the Turtlebot stack? If so, what would be the recommended IMU to buy?

Thanks,
-Scott

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9749/is-an-imu-required-to-run-turtlebot-stack?/) by [Scott](https://answers.ros.org/users/100/scott/) on ROS Answers with karma: 693 on 2011-04-16

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Scott](https://answers.ros.org/users/100/scott/) on 2011-04-26**:
Great suggestions. I will give them a go and see if that helps. Much appreciated.

**Comment by [JeffRousseau](https://answers.ros.org/users/75/jeffrousseau/) on 2011-04-25**:
Also, you'll have to comment out the URDF part of the create_bringup and replace it with your own (probably static) transforms for the Kinect and the imu (turtlebot calls the imu frame gyro_link)--unless you've somehow recreated the turtlebot in its entirety

**Comment by [JeffRousseau](https://answers.ros.org/users/75/jeffrousseau/) on 2011-04-25**:
PS Unless you have a really good network connection between nodes (underutilized 802.11N network) I'd suggest running the entire nav stack on a single machine.

**Comment by [JeffRousseau](https://answers.ros.org/users/75/jeffrousseau/) on 2011-04-25**:
Are you running different nodes on different machines? If so it sounds like you have a clock skew problem. Try setting up NTP/chrony: http://www.ros.org/wiki/Robots/TurtleBot/diamondback/Robot%20Setup#Setup_NTP

**Comment by [Scott](https://answers.ros.org/users/100/scott/) on 2011-04-23**:
Here are the errors I get on turtlebot_bringup [ERROR] [1303566596.868810887]: Timestamps of odometry and imu are 1.218011 seconds apart.
[ERROR] [1303566596.869189147]: filter time older than imu message buffer
[ERROR] [1303566597.380293912]: Could not transform imu message from  to base_footprint

**Comment by [Scott](https://answers.ros.org/users/100/scott/) on 2011-04-23**:
Issues with IMU odometry. I purchased and mounted the ADXRS613 as recommended below, but I am getting the following errors. As you can guess, the mapping is still off and it is likely due to the IMU not helping out with improved data due to the errors. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The Turtlebot uses a single-axis ADXRS613 rate gyro for its IMU, attached directly to the DB25 analog port of the iRobot Create base.  I'm using an ADXRS613 breakout from sparkfun found [here](http://www.sparkfun.com/products/9059) on my (non-turtelbot) Create--works great.

Hook the RATE pin from the ADXRS613 to the Analog Input (pin 4), connect the 5V on the breakout to the 5V on the DB25, and hook the GNDs together as well. Ignore the other pins on the ADXRS613 unless you want to figure out temperature compensation.

Also, make sure you run the Turtlebot calibration node to compensate for bias in the IMU. You should only have to do this once unless you drive your robot in varying environments--as the calibration routine compensates for wheel slippage as well as rate bias.

[image description http://farm1.static.flickr.com/129/374045585_ca403e987c.jpg](http://farm1.static.flickr.com/129/374045585_ca403e987c.jpg)

---

Originally posted by [JeffRousseau](https://answers.ros.org/users/75/jeffrousseau/) with karma: 1607 on 2011-04-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Scott](https://answers.ros.org/users/100/scott/) on 2011-04-18**:
Very cool and thanks for the great detials. Can't wait to try it out. -Scott

**Comment by [张京林](https://answers.ros.org/users/19842/%E5%BC%A0%E4%BA%AC%E6%9E%97/) on 2015-10-26**:
But how to set the bias in the IMU? After the calibration node estimating the imu drift, which parameter should I change?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's not required but it makes the odometry much better.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-04-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3